# Tool to trace packets within same machine

Tags: windows, sockets, network-programming, wireshark

Wireshark like tools can capture in coming or out going messages to our machine, is there any tool available which trace packets communication between our own machine. Like if I have client and server on same machine but port is different is it possible to trace packets?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows TCP/IP stack does not implement a network loopback lo interface. See [this](http://www.hsc.fr/ressources/articles/win_net_srv/missing_loopback.html) page, for information.

You can instead use RawCap for your purpose, look it up [here](http://www.netresec.com/?page=Blog&month=2011-04&post=RawCap-sniffer-for-Windows-released). You can use the command `RawCap.exe 127.0.0.1 dumpfile.pcap`

Answer (score 0):

Select interface "lo" in wireshark , for getting the packets in the same pc.

Thanks,
Justin Jose

Comment: I do not have any such interface listed. Do I need to do any setting.

Comment: Yes, you need to set your operating system to "Linux". :-)  Justin Jose's answer is correct for Linux, but is not correct for Windows (nor is it correct for \*BSD, OS X, Solaris 11, and some other UN\*Xes, where the interface is "lo0").